# How to update JLabel from action listener?

Tags: java, actionlistener

Explanation:

---

I have an int variable to keep track of how many times button is pushed.

I have a JLabel that shows this variable in the form of a string basically.

When I click Add, I want the variable to update and then the jlabel to show the updated variable.

I have a secondary button listener class that implements the actionlistener code. I can't post all my code because my professor is strict about her plagiarism checks.

EDIT:

I see when I add the JLabel.setText to the action listener, it will update. Not sure if this is the best method.

Code:

---

```
int counter = 0;

JLabel label = new JLabel("Count is: " + counter);

JButton increment = new JButton("Increment Here");

increment.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
```

My button listener class contains this code:

```
counter++;
```

Let me know if more code is necessary, I am just trying to simplify my issue. I tried adding an UpdateUI(); method, but nothing happened.

Answer (score 2):

in your Button Action Listener

Write

```
label.setText("Count is: " + counter);
```

After the Increment to count variable

Comment: Yup, you posted that exactly as I realized. Wasn't sure if this was the best method. Thanks.

Comment: I am semi beginner Like you, and use this method whenever i wan't to update a Label on run time, But as point of efficiency i am not sure that whether this is best or not, let's the others decide that.